# Getting outerHTML code issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my js code:

```
function myfunction(){
    $("#label_startDate[0]")[0].outerHTML;
}
```

and this is the html part:

```
<label id="label_startDate[0]" class="" style="">
    <span id="star_startDate[0]" style="display: none; color: red">*</span>
    <input name="startDate[0]" id="startDate[0]" value="2015-06-02" readonly="" class="forDatePicker hasDatepicker" size="14" onchange="changeEndDate(0); calculateDaysDuration('@[0]', 0); "type="text">
</label>
```

For the reason that I have a weird format of the id from the label, I cannot get the `outerHTML`. What should I do ? I cannot change the id **label_starDate[0]**.

Comment: Consider using `document.getElementById(...)` instead. That's effectively what you're using anyway (and it will be hugely faster than the $ selector).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\\` to escape `[]` and also use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to access properties

```
 $("#label_startDate\\[0\\]").prop("outerHTML");
```

From [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.

```js
$(function() {
    alert( $("#label_startDate\\[0\\]").prop("outerHTML"))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="label_startDate[0]" class="" style="">
                        <span id="star_startDate[0]" style="display: none; color: red">*</span>
                        <input name="startDate[0]" id="startDate[0]" value="2015-06-02" readonly="" class="forDatePicker hasDatepicker" size="14" onchange="changeEndDate(0); calculateDaysDuration('@[0]', 0); "type="text">  
</label>
```

Comment: Thx a lot great solution and well explained